# Difference between Doze mode and power saving mode

Tags: android

I am trying to find a difference between doze mode and power saving mode. Are they related or not? So far I couldn't find a direct answer. I apologize if it's a simple or (stupid maybe) question.

Comment: Read this on Android Developers link https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html